# When to store pointers to structs in variables instead of the struct itself

Tags: go

I'm currently learning Go and am following a tutorial about how to use Go with Stripe. There is this example code:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/stripe/stripe-go"
  "github.com/stripe-go/customer"
)

func main() {
  sc := &client.API{}
  sc.Init("somekey")
  c, _ := sc.Customers.Get("customerid", nil)
  // ...
}
```

What is/could be the reason that `sc` stores the pointer to the struct and not the struct itself?

Comment: As far as this small and incomplete code snippet is concerned it doesn't matter if `sc` is a pointer or not, all the statements in it will produce the same output/behaviour. So without seeing the whole code, one can only speculate what the reason is/could be. And, just so you don't get your hopes up, even if we would inspect the full sample it is possible that the rest of the code is just as elementary, i.e. doing nothing that would *require* the variable to be a pointer,  which will render the answer to your question: "author's preference".

Comment: > "author's preference". Thanks, I assumed that there would be an obvious reason for it which I just am not aware of as I'm not so familiar with the language. Go seems like a language with clear rules on when to do what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[To supplement the comment you received]

While in this case with the small code sample it's hard to say, in most scenarios you'll see non-trivial types passed around by pointer to enable modification. As an anti-example, consider this code which uses a variable of a struct type by value:

```
type S struct {
    ID int
}

func (s S) UpdateID(i int) {
    s.ID = i
}

func main() {
    s := S{}
    s.UpdateID(99)

    fmt.Println(s.ID)
}
```

What do you think this will print? It will print 0, because methods with value receivers cannot modify the underlying type.

There's much information about this in Go - read about pointers, and about how methods should be written. This is a good reference: https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers, and also https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#pointers_vs_values

Back to your example: typically non-trivial types such as those representing a "client" for some services will be using pointers because method calls on such types should be able to modify the types themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Given your code example, if I would just modify `func (s S) UpdateID(i int)` to be `func (s *S) UpdateID(i int)` instead, the mutation would already work, without having to change `s` to store the pointer. That's part of what's confusing me.

Comment: @Linus: that's a bit of magic Go does, when you call `s.Method` and `Method` has a pointer receiver, the call is actually translated to `(&s).Method`, so while you "store" the value, a pointer is passed around. It's cleaner to just store the pointer though, and is the accepted practice, though in many cases storing a value will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this @Eli Bendersky.